# Why is my question still on hold despite of being narrowed down and added explanation?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed, on-hold

I asked a question several days ago, and soon after being posted it was set to "on hold". The reason being that it was too general.

I tried explaining more and the question itself got edited as well, and I am 100% sure it is specific and thus should be set free from on-hold status.

Here is the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472802/how-to-get-the-port-numbers-each-application-uses-to-send-or-recieve-data-in-c

Comment: The issue I have with closing this question as a duplicate is that the answers on the listed duplicate do not *fully address* this user's problem. They have a specific question they're asking about, and they feel like they've added enough detail. They're here for *specific advice*, and that listed duplicate does not give *specific advice* about this *specific* issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-specific-file-is-open-in-windows

Comment: i asked my question in another forum and i got my answer: one of the ways is we can parse cmd's output ,with using "netstat -ano" this will show all tcp and udp with all information you need(not just tcp),and you can use "netstat -ano > result.txt" for save the output to a text file,and at last you can use "tasklist" for list the programm that is runnging with their names.with the 2 list that already you have ,you can do your job.I hope this will help others.

Answer (score 4):

This question still feels broad (maybe it isn't), but it feels like it.  If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want a mix of a program that scans ports for every application, and somehow filters out the system processes that are using network ports?

That' not a trivial program.

What do you really want?  Do you want to know how to do it? Do you want us to write that program for you? Do you want a small amount of code that shows you how to scan ports?  Are you ok if the answer is

> "That answer is too long to post here, you should probably read up on the subject more?"

Currently, that's exactly what the close reason is telling you, and unless you can narrow your question down a lot, we can't help you.

Comment: just please help.if you dont know the answer just go and let the question be open and other people see it.the question is realy trivial

Comment: i want to know the method (no code no programmm no other things,just method,but if you mention with some piece of code ,that will be realy good for me).let me say a sample:the nestsat -no in cmd show all port and protocol and pid of programm that in use tcp.i just want to know a method to give me a list like nestat but have udp and tcp in it's list

Comment: @Mahdi that's really broad for us.  "How does a computer determine what ports are in use?" Isn't really even a programming question, it's a computer architecture question. You should search on Google and read up on this; this isnt' the type of question we can help you with.  It's not as trivial as your question makes it out to be.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it is still too general. Your question it too broad, there are a lot of answers possible.

Something that could help is [adding some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you have tried.

Also, in the [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can be found useful information about asking good questions.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely too broad, and it doesn't show how much effort you have already put into solving the problem. Spending 30 minutes or more on making a clearly worded, precise question, which shows your efforts so far, and describes the problem in a way which can attract focused answers will instantly reward you.

If you haven't already, take a look at [Writing the perfect question](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) by Jon Skeet.